# Não consigo utilizar boundary(\b) para validar uma palavra que comece com "@"

Tags: regex

No caso de /\b@MYVAR\b/i, eu não consigo utilizaro boundary,  Vide: https://regex101.com/r/4bFElA/1 
Eu preciso validar uma string que contenha uma palavra @MYVAR (Exemplo).

Há alguma restrição quanto à este caracter? Qual seria uma alternativa?

Fiz um teste em javascript e o resultado é falso.

```js
console.log(`/\b@MYVAR\b/i.test("@MYVAR")`,/\b@MYVAR\b/i.test("@MYVAR"));
```

Em php o código ficaria algo assim:

```
<?php
$value = "@MYVAR";
if(preg_match("#/\b@MYVAR\b/i#i", trim($value))){
 echo "ok";
}
```

Comment: Em que linguagem vais usar essa regex? Podes explicar melhor o problema que estás a tentar resolver?

Comment: Preciso validar uma string que contenha uma palavra @MYVAR, postei um exemplo em javascript mas poderia ser em php  ou outra linguagem qualquer.

Comment: amigo, já tentou usar a regex (@userid)? @LeonanCarvalho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O boundary (`\b`) se aplica apenas a letras, números e o underline que seria o equivalmente ao `\w` (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) por isso sua regex falha.

Nesse caso teria que deixar a arroba fora do boundary. Algo como `@\buserid\b` ou `@?\buserid\b`

Comment: Apenas um detalhe `\w` = [`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`](https://regex101.com/r/2KprQT/1)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert obrigado pela correção já editei :)

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que `@` não é considerado um caracter válido para `word`. Ou seja: `\b` refere-se ao inicio de uma palavra mas os caracteres válidos para `\w` são `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, e `@` não está lá.

Comment: mais rapido que eu, DAMN

Comment: @Paz sorry :) Fica para a próxima :)

Comment: Vocês se movem tão rápido que meus olhos mal podem acompanhá-los!

Answer (score 4):

Complementando o conceito:

O `\b` não faz seleção. Ele é um `anchor` assim como `^` e `$` e posiciona o cursor para as posições que estão entre: `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`. Em outras palavras:

- No começo da string, dado que o primeiro *char* seja um *char word*.
- No fim da string, dado que o último *char* seja um *char word*.
- No meio da string, onde um *char* é uma *word* e o outro não.

É considerado um *char word* o que estiver em `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, ou seja, letras, dígitos e underline.

Por exemplo: dito `"i'm looking @ you"`, o `\b` posicionaria (vou marcar com *|*):

```
|i|'|m| |looking| @ |you|
```

Acho que essas considerações podem ser útil para alguns.

Answer (score 2):

Como citado pelos anciões **rray** e **Sergio**, uma word boundary é definida por iniciar em caracteres `[a-z A-Z 1-9]`, porém isso pode ser revertido com uma regex como essa:

```
(@\buserid\b)
```

**Explicação:**
Essa regex identifica o caractere @ e só da match se existir a palavra "userid" em seguida.